# Entity Framework Update Time & Date Column with Parameterized

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have changed all my code from the raw `ADO.NET` `SQLCommand` to `Entity Framework` in order to have easier accessibility of changing my code in the future. However, I have realized there are many drawbacks in `Entity Framework` it is not as simple as injecting raw `SQL` commands into the database. Moreover, I have used `Reverse Engineering` to generate the `Models & Mapping` for `MS Sql Server`.

Currently, I am trying to do the following but none of the columns are getting updated.

```
string sql = @"UPDATE [ProductDB] SET CreatedProduct_Time=getdate(), CreatedProduct_Date=getdate()" + " WHERE [Material_No] = @Material_No";

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, new SqlParameter("@Material_No", materialnotxt));
```

The columns are not getting updated.

I am having a doubt whether `Entity Framework` will help me maintain my code for future use and is it worth the headache using it instead of the old `raw SQL code`? So far there are many constraints and it requires a higher learning curve.

Some confusing parts I have find online what is the difference between the `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` and this `MSDN` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738684.aspx the code looks entirely different then my approach.

**EDIT**

I have used a different approach to insert the `Date` and `Time` while inserting all the info from the `textbox`.

```
using (var db = new ROGContext())
        {

            ProductDB product = new ProductDB
            {
                Material_No = long.Parse(MaterialNo_txtbox.Text),
                Product_Line = ProductLineDropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text,
                Product_Description = Description_txtbox.Text,
                Size = Size_txtbox.Text,
                UOM = UOM_txtbox.Text,
                SupplierID = long.Parse(SupplierCountryListBox.SelectedItem.Value),
                CreatedProduct_Date = DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()), //in the SQL database I have set the datatype as date to get yyyy/mm/dd
                CreatedProduct_Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay  //in the SQL database I have set the datatype as time(0) to get hh:mm:ss
            };

            long queryselect = (from materialno in db.ProductDBs
                               where materialno.Material_No == product.Material_No
                               select materialno.Material_No).SingleOrDefault();

            if (queryselect != long.Parse(materialnotxt))
            {
                Label1.Text = "Product successfully added in database";
                Label1.Visible = true;
                db.ProductDBs.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();             
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Context.ExecuteStoreCommand` for Insert, Update and Delete.

See in Page 64 of [Entity Framework 4.0 Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach](http://books.google.com/books?id=wB3ACQzTeRAC&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=ExecuteStoreCommand&source=bl&ots=flkXNxXYGB&sig=Dc-YFF4BKgzg3xMcNTH7hSmZOm8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WTs6UbGOLbPg2wWot4GIAw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=ExecuteStoreCommand&f=false)

**Answer your edited part:**

1. `ExecuteStoreQuery` for Select
2. `ExecuteStoreCommand` for Insert, Update and Delete

[Entity Framework v4 – Tips and Tricks](http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2010/06/23/entity-framework-v4-ndash-tips-and-tricks.aspx)